# How compute Index of element in a list?

Tags: prolog

I am starting to play with prolog, and with a Java background it's really difficult for me so here is a silly question:

How will you write an indexOf predicate able to give the index of a given element in a given list ?

My first question is about the predicate arity: I guess it should be 3 such as:

```
indexOf(List,Element, Index) :- ......
```

Am I right ? May be this already exists in built-in libraries but I want to learn how to write it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like a good start.

Comment: @aschepler yes but I am getting crazy to have this little predicate working !!!

Comment: This is indeed a good exercise when learning prolog. FYI: the building predicates to achieve this are `nth0` and `nth1`. (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it recursively: Suppose 0-based index (otherwise just change the 0 with 1 on the first clause)

```
indexOf([Element|_], Element, 0). % We found the element
indexOf([_|Tail], Element, Index):-
  indexOf(Tail, Element, Index1), % Check in the tail of the list
  Index is Index1+1.  % and increment the resulting index
```

If you want only to find the first appearance, you could add a cut (!) to avoid backtracking.

```
indexOf([Element|_], Element, 0):- !.
indexOf([_|Tail], Element, Index):-
  indexOf(Tail, Element, Index1),
  !,
  Index is Index1+1.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can I replace the first clause with: indexOf([First|_], Element, Index) :- First == Element, Index == 0. ?

Comment: The answer is NO. Can you explain why ?

Comment: The == operator does not perform unification. Thus, it cannot instantiate Index to 0. It can be used, however, in the first comparison (First==Element would be fine because in that predicate both terms should be instantiated). Index==0 will fail when Index is not instantiated.

Comment: Ok thanks for this clear explanation. One more question, I read the = operator can be used for unification. Thus I guess replacing the first clause with: indexOf([First|_], Element, Index) :- First == Element, Index = 0 will work ? Do you confirm ? I am at office, I'll try this at home tonight.

Comment: Yes, it would work. Note that indexOf([First|_], Element, Index):- First == Element, Index = 0. is almost the same as indexOf([First|_], Element, 0):- First == Element. In the latter case the unification is done in the head of the predicate instead of the body. Actually the latter would be the same as indexOf([First|_], Element, Index):- Index = 0, First == Element. so the unification would be performed before the comparison.

Comment: I think the second cut is unnecessary.@gusbro

Comment: If you wanted to compute the element in a list of lists? Could this be easily extended?

Comment: @AndrewCaulfield: Yes, if you want to get # of list and # of item in that list you would have use two counters and recurse into every sublist.

Comment: @gusbro Not looking to get the # of list. Just the position of an element inside a list of lists. so print_position([[b,c,f],[a,d,g],[h,e]],g,H) would return H = 2.

Comment: Yes, that would be easy too. I would use a procedure that iterates over the list of lists, and for each list you may call the procedure of this answer. Alternatively, just issue `member(List, ListOfLists), indexOf(List, Element, Index)`

Comment: What would the full predicate be? I'm getting an error on my end.

Comment: It would be something like this: `indexOfInListOfLists(ListOfLists, Element, Index):- member(List, ListOfLists), indexOf(List, Element, Index).`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

One should prefer to use tail-recursion:

```
indexOf(V, [H|T], A, I)
:-
    Value = H, A = I, !
;
    ANew is A + 1,
    indexOf(V, T, ANew, I)
.

indexOf(Value, List, Index)
:-
    indexOf(Value, List, 0, Index)
.

indexOfWithoutFailure(Value, List, Index)
:-
    indexOf(Value, List, 0, Index)
;
    Index = -1
.
```

Some example queries:

```
?- indexOf(d, [a, b, c, d, e, f], Index).
Index = 3.

?- indexOf(x, [a, b, c, d, e, f], Index).
false.

?- indexOfWithoutFailure(x, [a, b, c, d, e, f], Index).
Index = -1.
```

If you want to get all indexes of an element in a list, you should write another predicate for it without the cut named allIndexesOf or something.

Answer (score 1):

I made this in successor notation and it's quite concise and neat:

```
index([V|_],V,0).
index([_|T],V,s(I)) :- index(T,V,I).
```

sample outputs:

```
?- index([a,b,c,a],a,X).
X = 0 ;
X = s(s(s(0))) ;
false.

?- index(List,a,s(0)).
List = [_G1710, a|_G1714].
```